# When I upload the output of PEPK tools, Google Play Console says "The certificate provided is invalid. Please submit a different certificate."

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, android-app-signing

This is the command I executed in my computer according to Google Play:

```
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=foo --output=output.zip --encryptionkey=blabla --include-cert
```

and I uploaded the `output.zip`. Google Play Console told me that:

> The certificate provided is invalid. Please submit a different certificate.

Besides, there are two files in the `output.zip`: `certificate.pem` and `encryptedPrivateKey`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens when your key expires too soon. Did you create your key with keytool with a default key validity period?

In the new console, the error message is different and even less descriptive:

> The private key was not properly encrypted or is not a type of key that we support.

In the end I resolved this by using Android Studio to create the key store with the default 25 year key validity period.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error, the reason is very simple but it took me a lot of time, private key file only need to upload once, instead the second upload will report this error, I have suggested Google to change this error description, too confusing.

Whether it is Internal test or Production, the key only needs to be uploaded once.