# The private key was not properly encrypted or is not a type of key we support

Tags: android, google-play-console

When I upload my zip file in Google Play Console, it is not accepted. What did I do I see this notification?

> The private key was not properly encrypted or is not a type of key we support.

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44103024/how-to-enable-google-play-app-signing

Comment: The same message as yours is found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63652831/9298629).

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this error, the reason is very simple but it took me a lot of time, private key file only need to upload once, instead the second upload will report this error, I have suggested Google to change this error description, too confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you open the page or maybe download the new PEM file it *GENERATES A NEW ONE* and *apparently invalidating the old one*.

So if you are struggling to create a private key and accidently press the button again, I think your old PEM file is not valid anymore.

So the conclusion is: you have to do it in one go.

Comment: yes indeed!!!!!

Comment: Worked as charm.

Answer (score 0):

To generate private encrypted key use below commands in terminal (Mac)

```
java -jar /Users/jhon/Documents/pepk.jar --keystore=/Users/jhon/Documents/Keystore/mykeystore.jks --alias=ka0 --output=/Users/jhon/Documents/SignedApk/TestApp/encryptedkey --rsa-aes-encryption --encryption-key-path=/Users/jhon/Documents/SignedApk/TestApp/encryption_public_key.pem
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

First, verify that `encryption_public_key.pem` is valid. Ensure that you didn't copy-pasted from another project.

Second, uploading the certificate is not intuitive. Once you uploaded (even without app publishing) the certificate is applied. Navigate to `Setup` ->`App Signing`, double check wether the certificate signature equals to the one you uploaded. If everything is correct - do **not** select `Export and upload a key from Java keystore` anymore option but `Let Google manage and protect your app signing key (recommended)` and upload app bundle (`.aab`) signed with your release or upload certificate. The Google will use provided keystore (that you also have) and sign the app